# Unable to assign button id with a value returned by a function

Tags: javascript

I want to add id for the button dynamically. I used a javascript method returing the id. But I'm not getting the output. Button is inside the script.
Here is my code for button:

```
 $("#classes").append("<button id='"+assignID(bname,cid);+"'>Modify</button>");
```

I made a method assignID(para1,para2).

```js
function assignID(bname,cid)
{
 var concatID=bname+"_"+cid;
 return concatID;
}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the middle of the expression.

Comment: Thanks.. its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon assignID(bname,cid) after

```
 $("#classes").append("<button id='"+assignID(bname,cid)+"'>Modify</button>");
```